# I am trying to validate the following in page: Unit testing text and existence of Test Automation Interface Model picture

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, nunit, specflow

I am using the C# selenium, Specflow and Nunit3 for performing above task. 
I am confused that how to validate the page. Later on, following task already i have done. Moreover, it Search for the link of Behavior driven development and navigates there.

Steps:

1. Navigate to the [Wikipedia][1] site.
2. Choose the English language
3. Search for "Test Automation”

---

```
[TestFixture]
public class ChromeTesting : Hooks
{
    [Test]
    public void ChromeWikipediaTest()
    {
        //1-  Navigate to the Wikipedia site
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.wikipedia.org");

          //2- Get the search results panel that contains the link for each result.
          Driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).SendKeys("Test Automation");


            Driver.FindElement(By.Name("go")).Click();
           Assert.That(Driver.PageSource.Contains("Test Automation"), Is.EqualTo(true),
                                                     "Test Automation Does not Exits");

    }
}}
```

Comment: What you tried so far? Source code? Errors?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's unclear what you're asking. It stuns me how many posts are made on this stack, by testers, without enough information in them. Testing 101 - there's (almost) no such thing as too much detail.

Comment: @theonlydanever I am performing a task that: 
*Navigate to the Wikipedia site.
 *Choose the English language
 *Search for "Test Automation”. I have done till here.                                                                Now I need to validate the following in this page: 1- Unit testing text and 2-  Existence of Test Automation Interface Model picture
3- Search for the link of Behavior driven development and navigate to there.  I am using C# Selenium, Specflow for BDD, Nunit 3 for performing all above task.

Comment: @PeterMasiar   I have done this so far . I needed to validate the pages: i.e. unit testing text and Existence of Test Automation Interface Model picture also this search for the link of Behavior driven development and navigate to there.

Answer (score 0):

the below are in java/selenium.

1. Unit Testing word presents

   List p = driver.findElements(By.tagName("P"));
                   for(WebElement e:p)
                   {
                       if(e.getText().contains("unit testing"))
                       {
                           System.out.println("Present");
                       }
                   }

   2. Test Automation Interface Model picture

   if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/div[4]/div/a/img")).isDisplayed())
           {
               System.out.println("Present");
           }

   3. Link Click

   List G = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
           for(WebElement d:G)
           {
               if (d.getText().contains("Behavior driven development")) 
               {
                   driver.get(d.getAttribute("href"));
               }
           }

Comment: Thanks for your guidance which helps me a bit but i want to have it in C#.